# How do I get ABP Application Service routing to multiple implementations?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, interface, asp.net-mvc-routing, aspnetboilerplate

I am using ASP.NET Boilerplate (ABP).

I want to have a generic application service that is implemented in multiple ways. Reading the documentation, it appears that it requires me to create an interface for each class. I want to have one generic interface and be able to route it to the implemented classes. Is there any way to do this?

```
public interface IMyAppService : IApplicationService
{
    Task<DataTableCollection> PostData(string action, string data);
}

public class myclass1 : IMyAppService
{
    public async Task<DataTableCollection> PostData(string action, string data)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class myclass2 : IMyAppService
{
    public async Task<DataTableCollection> PostData(string action, string data)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then in my application, access them via routes like **/app/myclass1** and **/app/myclass2**.

Comment: Maybe this is the right scenario to use `Dependency Injection`

Answer (score 0):

That should already work. The interface for each class is recommended (though not necessary) for Dependency Injection, but that's irrelevant here.

You just need to implement the [`IApplicationService` Interface](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Application-Services#iapplicationservice-interface).

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this to generalize CRUD operations, there's already such an interface `AsyncCrudAppService`

```
public class TaskAppService : AsyncCrudAppService<Task, TaskDto>, ITaskAppService
{
    public TaskAppService(IRepository<Task> repository) 
        : base(repository)
    {

    }
}
```

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Application-Services#crudappservice-and-asynccrudappservice-classes